# Is there a way to know if a Google Map did or didn't load?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a mapView on my App. Everytime it loads the MyLocation Button but sometimes it doesn´t load the actual map, maybe Connection issue APIKey issue, or something similar.

Is there a way to know if the map did or didn't load?

Not the mapView because it loads the MyLocation button, I mean the actual map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this answers your question [OnMapLoadedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.html).

Comment: It works thank you, now I'm just missing a callback if it didn´t load. I guess you need to make a timer and decide when you declare the map as dead.

Answer (score -1):

You can verify that the GoogleMap is available by calling the `MapFragment.getMap()` or `MapView.getMap()` methods and checking that the returned object is not null.

Comment: In your case use MapView.getMap()

Comment: getMap This method is deprecated.

Comment: Oh is it.. I developed an app using gmaps around 6 months back.. Hence answered as per my knowledge.. Didn't crosscheck if its deprecated now.. Thanks for the info.. However, please suggest which method has replaced it now?